# mysql create table and get error 1064

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE course000 (
id_number int(9) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL default '000000000',
grade_1 int(3) default NULL,
grade_2 int(3) default NULL,
grade_final int(3) default NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id_number)
);
```

Please help me; why can't I use this code to build mysql table?

Comment: just put `,` after **grade_1 int(3) default NULL**

Comment: just copy my answer and try

Answer (score 0):

```
grade_1 int(3) default NULL//you have missing ,(comma here)
```

Answer (score 0):

just put `,` after **grade_1 int(3) default NULL**

```
CREATE TABLE course000 (
id_number int(9) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL default '000000000',
grade_1 int(3) default NULL,
grade_2 int(3) default NULL,
grade_final int(3) default NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id_number)
);
```